# Box shadow not rounding

Tags: html, css

So i'm working on this website - 
http://www.roseandlilyprinting.com/

If you go to the port-folio section you would see that the box shadow is not rounding to suite the border radius making the box shadow disrupt the feel

Here's the CSS Snippet the #navBarPort is what has the box shadows along with #allImages

Thanks for your help

```css
#navBarPort {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 55px auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999,
    2px 2px 2px #999,
    3px 3px 3px #999,
    4px 4px 4px #999,
    5px 5px 5px #999,
    6px 6px 6px #999,
    7px 6px 7px #999,
    8px 6px 8px #999,
    9px 6px 9px #999;
}


#navBarPort a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 39px;
    line-height: 37px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #315218;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navBarPort a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #27A5BA;
}

#navBarPort a.active{
    color: #27A5BA;
}


/*----------------------------
 Content area
-----------------------------*/
#images {
    height: 460px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;

}


#allImages{
    display:block;
    height: 490px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px #999;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#allImages li{

    float: left;
    height: 96px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 6px;
    position: relative;
    width: 115px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

#allImages ul li img{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#allImages ul{
    overflow:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#allImages ul.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Visited the link...after 30 second the page hadn't loaded...so I gave up.

Comment: Please change this: border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; to this: border-radius: 10px; This makes it more readable and removes redundant code.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz _“Omit things in your code whenever you can.”_ But not in the sense of code-golfing, right? I’d reword it as “Make code as readable as possible and remove as much redundancy as possible”.

Comment: @Xufox Very true, I've re-phrased my comment accordingly. Cheerios.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz actually I was doing it that way to try an fix it by changing values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your box shadows are cut off because of the `overflow: hidden` property on the div element with class `flex-viewport`.

Note that box shadows don't necessarily stay within an element's bounding box, and thus can be considered overflow.

Note that removing that property will interfere with the flex slider, but it's possible to find a workaround (for example, setting `overflow: hidden` on a parent element).

Comment: Can u help me find which parent element? I'm a bit new to css3

Comment: Your best bet is to use "inspect element" and try moving the property to various parents. see which one works out the best and needs the least modification. :)

Comment: I figured it out bro thanks I see where the overflow u were talking about